# Automate creation of PulseAudio null sinks

Tags: command-line, pulseaudio

I've recently swapped to Ubuntu and am trying to emulate what I used to do with [virtual audio cable](http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm) on Windows. I found a [great tutorial](https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/include-exclude-audio-sources-using-pulseaudio-linux.95/) that does exactly what I want it to do, but it of course becomes a little tiresome to type in all these verbose commands every time I have to restart the machine. My commands are as follows:

```
pactl load-module module-null-sink sink_name=GAME sink_properties=device.description="GAME"
pactl load-module module-null-sink sink_name=MUSIC sink_properties=device.description="MUSIC"
pactl load-module module-combine-sink sink_name=GAME_and_out sink_properties=device.description="GAME_and_out", slaves=0,1
pactl load-module module-combine-sink sink_name=MUSIC_and_out sink_properties=device.description="MUSIC_and_out", slaves=0,2
```

I want to move the required commands into my `.profile` file, but this duplicates the procedure every time I log in, leading to the creation of many extra sinks that I don't need nor want.

Is there a way to either remove the old null sinks created with `pactl load-module module-null-sink`, or write an `if` block to wrap it in that will not fire if those sinks already exist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rater than putting these commands into our `.profile` it is recommended to add all modules needed into our `/etc/pulse/default.pa` or in a copy of this file in our home in `~/.pulse/default.pa` resp. `~/.config/pulse/default.pa` for a per user setting (which will override all settings defined in `/etc/pulse/default.pa`).

Adding these lines to this file:

```
load-module module-null-sink sink_name=GAME sink_properties=device.description="GAME"
load-module module-null-sink sink_name=MUSIC sink_properties=device.description="MUSIC"
load-module module-combine-sink sink_name=GAME_and_out sink_properties=device.description="GAME_and_out", slaves=0,1
load-module module-combine-sink sink_name=MUSIC_and_out sink_properties=device.description="MUSIC_and_out", slaves=0,2
```

will always load the desired NULL sinks on starting the pulseaudio sound server.

Removing sinks that had been loaded by `pactl` or `pacmd`, i.e. without settings in our `default.pa` can most quickly done by

```
pulseaudio -k
```

This command will kill the running pulseaudio instance, to instantaneaously respawn it (in a default set up) using values defined in the `default.pa`.

Comment: That's *beyond* a perfect solution. It corrected a misconception, gave a solution, and gave me the answer to the final XY problem I asked as an addition. Thank you so much!

Comment: I found it necessary (Ubuntu 18, pulseaudio 11.1) to quote sink properties as `sink_properties="device.description='GAME'"`